# Convert from list to number

Tags: python-3.x, list, math, integer, documentation

I need to convert a singol list number in to a integer in order to make some math.

Could anyone help me?

I tried to use the map function but i cannot find the right documentation for python3.

Could anyone help me, please?

anthor question, since i mistake with the code, i need to associate a letter of alphabet to a number of interi list, could anyone help me ?

```
amount = int(input('valore dell ammontare?: ')) 

n = int(input('numero delle monete: ')) 

interi = []

for i in range(n): 

     numero = int(input('Inserisci valore delle monete: ')) 

     interi.append(numero) 

  a = interi[0:1] 
  b = interi[1:2] 
  c = interi[2:3] 
  d = interi[3:4] 
  e = interi[4:5] 

  y = a + b + c + d + e \\ here i need to trasform string to int if

  if amount == y:
  print('1') 
  else: 
  print('0')
```

Comment: Could you be more specific and maybe post uour coding startkng point ? Which operation do you want to apply on your list to make it a single number ? Sum all numbers?

Comment: In any case it looks more like a job for a `reduce` than a `map`.

Comment: @CarloVitale Edit your question and add this code

Answer (score 1):

As you only sum the items of a list you can simply use `sum(list)`.

You already convert your inputs to `int` so you don't need to do it again.

```py
amount = int(input('valore dell ammontare?: ')) 
n = int(input('numero delle monete: ')) 

interi = []

for i in range(n): 
    numero = int(input('Inserisci valore delle monete: ')) 
    interi.append(numero)

y = sum(interi) # You don't have to store each item of the list separately to use them

# If there is a reason to use only the 5 first items like you were doing, you could eventually do:
# y = sum(interi[:5]

if amount == y:
    print('1') 
else: 
    print('0')
```

Note that in a real world case you would have to handle the case where the user didn't type a number and then the `int("anyghing non digit")` would throw an error. So you could replace the line

```py
numero = int(input('Inserisci valore delle monete: '))
```

By

```py
user_input = input('Insert value')

while not user_input.isdigit(): 
    # ensure value is a number before trying to convert it to an int.
    user_input = input("Invalid input, please insert a number")
    
numero = int(user_input)
```